# Initialize length of ObservableCollection<T> the way you initialize a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

Is there any way to initialize the capacity of an `ObservableCollection<T>` like you can a `List<T>`?

For example:

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>(100);
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I suspect that `new List<int>(100)` *doesn't* do what is expected - it creates a list with an initial [*Capacity*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is rarely needed) and *not* "100 default elements" (which would affect the [*length/Count*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: I want to do this because of what I read in the List<T> documenatation on MSDN "If the size of the collection can be estimated, specifying the initial capacity eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations while adding elements to the List<T>."

Comment: @tnw: It is more efficient if you have a list that is large to not have to continually grow the array that the list uses underneath. You should look into List<T>.Add to see what goes on underneath. This can greatly reduce memory allocations and peformance when loading large sets of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question. But, I thought it might be worthwhile to know that currently, it is possible to set the backing List capacity at the risk of relying on the internal implementation.

The Items property that is exposed by the base `Collection<T>` class is currently implemented as a `List<T>`. With type casting, you can set that property's Capacity.

Note that this does rely on the current implementation of both the `List<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>` classes. If it is critical that you be able to set the backing Capacity and not worry that the .NET implementation will change (for instance, changing the backing list to a Dictionary or HashSet), you should instead create a new class that implements your needed interfaces.

You can use the [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs) as well as [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

Answer (score 10):

No there is not. [One of the constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202.aspx) for `ObservableCollection<T>` takes a `List<T>`, so you might think you can do this:

```
new ObservableCollection<int>(new List<int>(100));
```

But that doesn't work. Internally, `ObservableCollection` copies the list and doesn't take into account any capacity properties on the list. You can verify this by looking at the constructors using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

Comment: I looked into the constructor like you suggested and saw that it does initialize the internal list to the same length as the list you pass in. Thanks.

Comment: @user2449323 Yes, but **the length of the list being passed in here is zero, not 100**.  The *capacity* of the list is 100, but the length is zero as no items have been added to the list.